# Lock basket/order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a magento 2 plugin and I'm trying to find the best way to lock the basket to disable making changes to the basket.
The problem I'm facing is that users can initiate the checkout process but before completing the payment they might open the website again in a new browser tab/page and make changes to their basket in that new tab, I want to make sure users cannot change their basket if they have already started the checkout process.

I have been doing some reading but cannot find the best solution...